# Auto Resize Multiline Editable Text Field in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, autoresize

I'm looking auto-resize the font for each new line of equal width for a multi-line editable text field. Please check the url below:

http://api.pstr.co/html/template/003_script

Right now the font-size is like that

[image]

and I want to be like that:

[image]

The jquery code for this plugin is this:

```
    function getBaseFontSize(){
        var baseFontSize = Math.round(0.15*Math.min($(window).width(), $(window).height()));
        return baseFontSize;
    }


    function editModeSetup(){
        var contentBlock = $(".content");
        var container = $(".block");
        var scalableText = $(".scalable");

        $('[contenteditable]').each(function (index) {
            var $this = $(this);

            $this
            .on("keydown", function(){
                clearTimeout($this.timeout);
                fitTextMultiline(scalableText,contentBlock,container);
                //if (!$this.hasClass("edited")) $(this).addClass("edited");

             }).on("focus", function () {

                  //if (!$this.hasClass("edited")){
                        $this.selectText();
                  //}

                  // Work around Chrome's little problem
                  $this.mouseup(function() {
                                // Prevent further mouseup intervention
                                $this.unbind("mouseup");
                                return false;
                    });

            }).on("keyup", function () {

                $this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){ fitTextMultiline(scalableText,contentBlock,container); }, 400);
            });


        //$(".content").css("font-size", getBaseFontSize());
        $("html").css("font-size", getBaseFontSize()); 

        });

        fitTextMultiline(scalableText,contentBlock,container);

        $(window).resize(function() {
            fitTextMultiline(scalableText,contentBlock,container);    
        });

         var myWidth = window.innerWidth;
         var myHeight = window.innerHeight;

          ga('send',
           'event',
           'Viewport',
           'Size',
           myWidth+'x'+myHeight,
           {'nonInteraction': 1});


    }


    function fitTextMultiline(scalableText, contentBlock, container) {
        // startvwith small type and push the size up? to make sure more fits on one line...
        var maxHeight = container.height();
        var maxWidth = container.width();
        //console.log(".\n")
        //console.log(scalableText.text())
        var fontSize = 7*getBaseFontSize(); // 20;
        var fontUnits = "px"; // "vmin";

        do {
            scalableText.css('font-size', fontSize+fontUnits);
            contentHeight = contentBlock.height();
            contentWidth = contentBlock.width();
            //console.log("--- " + fontSize +" ---")
            //console.log(contentHeight + " ? " + maxHeight)
            //console.log(contentWidth + " ? " + maxWidth)
            fontSize = Math.round(fontSize - fontSize*0.1);

        } while ((contentHeight > maxHeight || contentWidth > maxWidth  ) && fontSize > 10);
    //+ fontSize/2


        alignPrices();
        doubleLineAssignClasses();
        return this;
    }


    // code that returns text from edit mode

    function getPosterText() {
    /*
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-61477423-5', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');
    */
        ga('send', 'event', 'Button', 'Save', document.title);

        var list = $('[contenteditable]').map(function () { 
            //console.log($(this).text());
            //console.log($(this).val());
            //console.log(_jsonEscape($(this).val()));

            //return $(this).text();
            return $(this).html();
        }).toArray();

        return _jsonEscape(JSON.stringify(list));
    }

    // code that sets text in edit mode


    function setPosterText(text) {


    /*
        var list;

        console.log(text)
        try {
            list = JSON.parse(text)
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log('Cannot parse given texts json.');
            list = [];

        }
    */
        //if (list.length > 0)

            /*
            $('[contenteditable]').each(function (index) {
                //$(this).text(list[index] || "");
                $(this).addClass("userText")
            });
        */

        //var contentBlock = $(".content");
        //var container = $(".block");
        //var scalableText = $(".scalable");

        //fitTextMultiline(scalableText,contentBlock,container);

    }

    function _jsonEscape(str)  {

        //str = str.replace(/&/g,"&amp;").replace(/£/g,"&pound;");
        //str.replace(/£/g,"&pound;");
        return str.replace(/\\n/g, "\\\\n").replace(/\\r/g, "\\\\r").replace(/\\t/g, "\\\\t");

    }

    function editableListFix(){
        $('ul').on('keyup keydown', function() {
      var $this = $(this);
        if (! $this.html()) {
            var $li = $('&lt;li&gt;&lt;/li&gt;');
            var sel = window.getSelection();
           var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.collapse(false);
            range.insertNode($li.get(0));
            range = range.cloneRange();
            range.selectNodeContents($li.get(0));
            range.collapse(false);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);

        } else {
            //are there any tags that AREN'T LIs?
            //this should only occur on a paste
            var $nonLI = $this.find(':not(li, br)');

            if ($nonLI.length) {
                $this.contents().replaceWith(function() {
        //we create a fake div, add the text, then get the html in order to strip out html code. we then clean up a bit by replacing nbsp's with real spaces
    return '&lt;li&gt;' + $('&lt;div /&gt;').text($(this).text()).html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ') + '</li>';
                });
                //we could make this better by putting the caret at the end of the last LI, or something similar
            }                   
        }
    });
    }



    function alignPricesFix(){
        alignPrices()


        $('[contenteditable]').each(function (index) {
            var $this = $(this);

            $this
            .on("keyup keydown", function(){
                alignPrices();
            });
        });
    }

    function alignPrices(){
        var positions = [];
        var heights = [];
        $( ".items>li" ).each(function( index ) {
            positions.push( $( this ).position().top );
            heights.push( $( this ).height() );
        });

        $( ".prices>li" ).each(function( index ) {
            //$( this ).css("top", positions[index]);
            $( this ).css("height", heights[index]);
        });

        ulPrices = $( "ul.prices" );
        if (ulPrices) ulPrices.css("height", $( "ul.items" ).height());

    }

    function doubleLineAssignClasses(){
        $( ".double-line>li" ).each(function( index ) {
            $( this ).removeClass('item-header');
            $( this ).removeClass('item-description');

            //if (!$( this ).hasClass('item-header') && !$( this ).hasClass('item-description') ){
            if (index % 2 != 1) $( this ).addClass('item-header')
            else  $( this ).addClass('item-description')  ;   
                //console.log(index);

        });


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check this website for the jQuery/javascript solution https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/is-it-possible-to-adapt-font-size-to-div-width/

I quote it here also:
"Hey, this isn’t going to be achievable with CSS alone, but you could certainly do this using jquery/javascript. For example you could enclose each word in a span, measure the width of that span, divide the width of the parent div by the span width, then multiply the font-size of the span text by that number.

i.e: (div width/span width) * span font-size"